# How do I make a list in alphabetical order and format it properly?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, format, alphabetical

I have a project question that says "Write a method that takes the user entered words/strings and sort them into alphabetical order."
I have the basic method worked out, but the problem is I need to format it like this:

```
1#....................(input1)
2#....................(input2)
```

for however many inputs they enter.
I can't quite figure out how to format it! I already have the counter in a for loop, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
def wordSort(wordList):
    sortedList = sorted(wordList)
    return sortedList

wordList = []

while True:
    word = raw_input("Please enter a word").title()

    if word == "*":
        break
    wordList.append (word)


print ("The words you are listed in alphabetical order are:")


wordSort(wordList)

sum = 0

for x in wordSort(wordList):
    sum = sum + 1

print ("#%d %s") %(sum, wordSort(wordList))
```

Comment: Your first call to `wordSort()` doesn't do anything. `sorted()` doesn't modify the original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your code, you can do this:

```
sortedWords = wordSort(wordList)
for x in sortedWords:
    print ("#%d %s") %(sum + 1, sortedWords[sum])
    sum = sum + 1
```

You can make it simpler using `enumerate()`:

```
sortedWords = wordSort(wordList)
for i, word in enumerate(sortedWords):
    print ("#%d %s") %(i, word)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate ?

Then iterate over the sorted and enumerated list

Ps: i would not define wordSort just to delegate to sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_words():
    words = []
    while True:
        word = raw_input('Please enter a word (or Enter to quit): ').strip().title()
        if word:
            words.append(word)
        else:
            return words

def main():
    words = get_words()

    print ("The words you entered, in alphabetical order, are:")
    for i,word in enumerate(sorted(words), 1):
        print('#{:>2d} {:.>16}'.format(i, ' '+word))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which results in

```
Please enter a word (or Enter to quit): giraffe
Please enter a word (or Enter to quit): tiger
Please enter a word (or Enter to quit): llama
Please enter a word (or Enter to quit): gnu
Please enter a word (or Enter to quit): albatross
Please enter a word (or Enter to quit): 
The words you entered, in alphabetical order, are:
# 1 ...... Albatross
# 2 ........ Giraffe
# 3 ............ Gnu
# 4 .......... Llama
# 5 .......... Tiger
```

Comment: How about: `'#{:>2} {:.>16}'.format(i, word)` (or maybe even `' '+word`) - to avoid the whole "leader" thingy

Comment: @Jon Clements: ooh, nice! Didn't know that one.

Comment: And your `get_words` could be (something like): `return [word.title() for word in iter(lambda: raw_input('Word: ').strip(), '')]`